# Scheme Programming compilation error

Tags: parsing, terminal, scheme, token, racket

The error I'm getting is missing an "else" expression in:

```
(if (not (eq? current_token next_token)) 
    (return #f))
```

I have the else statement in the image below as you can see. Just not sure why the program can't find it.

[scheme code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcuqa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the syntax of an [if](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=if) conditional is:

```
(if test-expr then-expr else-expr)
```

such that *if* `test-expr` produces any value other than `#f`, then `then-expr` gets evaluated, and if `#f` is produced, `else-expr` gets evaluated.

You currently have the following:

```
(if (not (eq? current_token next_token)) (return #f))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(if test-expr then-expr)
; test-expr = (not (eq? current_token next_token))
; then-expr = (return #f)
; Not complete - missing an else expression
```

Add an `else expression` to fix the problem.

For example:

```
> (if true 0)      ; test-expr = true, then-expr = 0
if: missing an "else" expression in: (if true 0)
> (if true 0 1)    ; test-expr = true, then-expr = 0, else-expr = 1
0
> (if false 0 1)   ; test-expr = false, then-expr = 0, else-expr = 1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Images are really poor way to include code in your questions. For **every** `if` you need 3 additional elements. `(if predicate consequence alternative)`. In the code you included there are the form `(not (eq? current_token next_token))` that is the predicate, then you have `(return #f)` which is the consequet, but you have no alternative for when the predicate is false. It has nothing to do with the `else` term in the `cond` because that is optional and it's a pert of the `cond` not the `if` that is in one of the `cond` consequents.

So how I see it when `current-token` and `next-token` both are symbols the conseqent is evaluated. Once a term hit it will it will do the consequences and not other tems will be visited. The `if` then checks if the two are the same. If they are not the same the error happens.